# annotation & regex

Tags: java, regex, annotations

I need to do a validation of an e-mail using annotation + regex. I tried to use the following:

```
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp=".+@.+\\.[a-z]+")
private String email;
```

However, I don't know how to print an error message when I have an incorrect e-mail address in the email field. Any ideas?

Comment: That depends on how you do the validation and where you want to print that message. Easy answer: `System.out.println(...)` :)

Comment: Sorry for the question, but why don't you use the @Email annotation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First you should add a `message` attribute to your `Pattern` annotation.
Assume that your mail variable is part of some class User:

```
class User{
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp=".+@.+\\.[a-z]+", message="Invalid email address!")
private String email;
}
```

Then you should define a validator:

```
ValidatorFactory vf = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = vf.getValidator();
User user = new User();
user.setEmail("user@gmail.com");
Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = validator
        .validate(user);
```

Then find validation errors.

```
for (ConstraintViolation<Object> cv : constraintViolations) {
      System.out.println(String.format(
          "Error here! property: [%s], value: [%s], message: [%s]",
          cv.getPropertyPath(), cv.getInvalidValue(), cv.getMessage()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As alluded to in the comments above:

```
@NotNull
@Email(message = "This email address is invalid")
private String email;
```