# Java negative lookahead not working

Tags: java, regex, annotations

I have the following regex `^(?!0{8})`, which should match any string that isn't 8 zeros. I can't see why this isn't working. I.e, 12345678 does not match.

I need to use regex as I'm using this in a `@Pattern` annotation, so I can't just do an equality check.

I've tested it on this site https://regex101.com/ and it seems perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show your Java code

Comment: *should match any string that isn't 8 zeros* - no, it won't, as it is a lookahead that does not consume anything. Use `(?s)^(?!0{8}$).*$` that should work.

Comment: To add to Wiktor's comment: the regex actually matches only the beginning of the line. Then it checks that the beginning is not followed by 8 zeros. Then you should actually match what you want. For example: .* will match anything. \d{8} will match 8 digits.

Comment: You may need change like : (?!0{8}).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made some mistakes in your regex. Checking if a string contains only 8 zeros. (According to your question, that is what you want to avoid) can be done with the regex `"^(0{8})$"`. This regex will return true if there are 8 zeroes in a row, and that is the only content in the string. `^` matches the beginning and 
`$`matches the end.

You can use java to negate the result.

```
    String s = "123456789";
    System.out.println(!s.matches("^(0{8})$"));
```

Comment: Well, I do not think a regex is necessary here at all then if this approach solves OP issue. I think OP regex is much longer and more complex, and the lookaround is necessary, but without seeing exact code and sample input, I am not sure.

Comment: Actually I want the negative of that, so not 8 zeros. I need to use regex as I'm using this in a @Pattern annotation, so I can't just do an equality check.

Comment: @wybourn yes, you could negate it with Java. check the updates answer

Answer (score 2):

Your lookahead lacks the `$` end of string anchor, and disallows matching any string *starting with* 8 zeros.

You need to use

```
^(?!0{8}$)
        ^
```

or - if the annotation pattern must match the entire string:

```
^(?!0{8}$).*$
```

Comment: Also, just in case you have other issue, the [*annotation & regex*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978199/annotation-regex) thread might be helpful.