# Validating if multiple java object fields is not null

Tags: java, validation, pojo

I want to check if the mandatory fields(name, age & postcode) contains value or is not null.

Typical way is

```
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("Cookie");
        person.setAge(20);

//validation
    if(person.getAge() != null && person.getName() != null){
        return true;
    }
```

In my original class I have over 20 fields that needs to be checked, therefore I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this?

**Simple POJO class example:**

```
public class Person {
 
   String name;
 
   int age;
 
   String address;
 
   int postcode;
 
   public Person() {
   }
 
   public String getName() {
      return this.name;
   }
 
   public void setName(String value) {
      this.name = value;
   }
 
//...etc setter and getters
}
```

Comment: You should re-design your class then. Try to initiate each variable with default values like 0 for int and empty string for a string and also, set your setter method to check for null content. With that way, you dont have to worry about NPEs but only for the content.

Comment: @Melron int automatically has 0 as default value. you're also altering functionality, "" is not a valid name so why should that validate to true?

Comment: @Stultuske yeah, i just saw `if(person.getAge() != null` and i thought there is some calc and as return an Integer class? About the name, its obviously better way to use `if (name.equals("something"))` than `if (name != null && name.equals("something"))`

Comment: @Stultuske – jepp, most probably, `""` (the empty String) is not a valid name, but nevertheless, it would validate to `true`, so the functionality would not be changed significantly by implementing Melron's suggestion.

Comment: Actually im getting the data back from an api, therefore I need to validate if the mandatory fields contains data. Is it not possible is stream through a object and check all fields without some?

Comment: @CookieMonster what type do you have for age?

Comment: @tquadrat technically speaking: no, functionally speaking, yes

Comment: @Stultuske its just an example POJO I gave. Most of the datatypes are object types not primitives,

Comment: If you're not able to use a validation framework (@NotNull, etc), then perhaps some (if not all) of the classes and/or fields should be immutable, with validation in the constructor.

Comment: A detail, an `int` cannot be `null`, so `person.getAge() != null` will always be true.

Answer (score 2):

Given that all your getters return a reference type (no primitives) and that you need to check only wether the result is `null` or not `null`, you can try this:

```
...
private final List<Supplier<Object>> m_Getters = new ArrayList<>();
...

public Person()
{
    m_Getters.add( this::getName );
    m_Getters.add( this::getAge ); // getAge() must return Integer, not int!!!
    m_Getters.add( this::getAddress );
    ...
 }

 ...

 public final boolean validate()
 {
      return m_Getters.stream().allMatch( s -> s.get() != null );
 }
```

You can also populate the list from the result of a reflection call, although you have to filter that result for the getters. And the predicate for `Stream.allMatch()` would be a bit more complex.

Answer (score 1):

## Bean Validation

I would suggest using [*Jakarta Bean Validation*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/), formerly known as *Java Bean Validation*.  See [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation), and [project home page](https://beanvalidation.org/).

```
Person person = … ;

Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate(person);

if (violations.isEmpty())
{
  …
}
```

Now you can annotate the fields for the required validations (here with [Lombok `@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) annotation to avoid all the getters and setters):

```
@Data
public class Person {
 
   @NotEmpty
   private String name;
 
   @Min(0)
   int age;
 
   @NotEmpty
   String address;
 
   @Min(0)
   int postcode;
 
}
```

BTW: I think int is not a good choice for postcode, especially for international use. Also instead of age I would recommend to use the date of birth for a persistent object.

Answer (score 0):

You could you the javax.validation. You can annotate your object with NotNull annotations. Then you can check it with a Validator.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978199/annotation-regex) example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the checking via **Java-reflection API**. Please see the doc [here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html).

Even if you don't use it this time, *reflective programming* is a good tool to keep it in mind.